# Emacs Telling IDO where to start searching

Tags: emacs, ido

I've used IDO in emacs for a while now, but it started opening in the /usr/bin folder instead of the usual home folder. How do I change it back?

Contents of the init file (if that helps):

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(defun toggle-fullscreen ()
  (interactive)
  (x-send-client-message nil 0 nil "_NET_WM_STATE" 32
       '(2 "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT" 0))
  (x-send-client-message nil 0 nil "_NET_WM_STATE" 32
       '(2 "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ" 0))
)
(toggle-fullscreen)
(global-linum-mode 1)
(ido-mode 1)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
(setq ido-everywhere t)
(setq inhibit-startup-message t
inhibit-startup-echo-area-message t)
(require 'recentf)
(recentf-mode 1)
(setq recentf-max-menu-items 25)
(global-set-key "\C-x\ \C-r" 'recentf-open-files)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "#000000" :foreground "#ffffff" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 110 :width normal :foundry "unknown" :family "Monospace"))))
 '(highlight ((((class color) (min-colors 88) (background dark)) (:background "#2f4f4f"))))
 '(hl-line ((t (:background "gray10")))))

(delete-selection-mode 1) 
(global-hl-line-mode 1) 
(setq make-backup-files nil) 
(setq auto-save-default nil) 
(global-visual-line-mode 1) 
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
(load "tabbar")
(tabbar-mode 1)
(load "bar-cursor")
(bar-cursor-mode 1)
(setq deft-directory "~/Dropbox/")
(setq deft-extension "org") (setq deft-text-mode 'org-mode)
(global-set-key [f8] 'deft)
(setq deft-use-filename-as-title t)
(require 'screenwriter)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") 'screenwriter-mode)
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.scp" . screenwriter-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.screenplay" . screenwriter-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(load "prelude-packages")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `M-x cd`.  It changes the `default-directory`, which is buffer local (it can have a different value for each buffer) and defaults to the directory of the buffer's file for buffers that have files.  I suppose you could loop over all buffers to set `default-directory` for all of them, but that sounds like a step backwards.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that when opening a new file (C-x C-f) it will start with the directory of the current buffer.

It can happen of course that you have some default settings due to changed customizations. Since you did not post anything relevant from your configuration I would suggest to do the following:

1. Check your .emacs / .emacs.d/init.el files for customizations to default directory locations
2. Check custom.el
3. Using M-x customize-group walk through the ido customizations

If all else fails perhaps you can post some of your recent configuration changes?

Hope it helps,

Arjen

Comment: Could you point me to the custom.el? I can't find it in the ido customizations...